# how to loop one radio button with different id

Tags: php, while-loop, radio-button

I'm trying to create a radio button in a loop, but I want to assign a unique id so it becomes a group where only one radio can be selected. Is this possible? My loop duplicates the same radio and I can select every button. I only want to select one.

```
<?php

$i = 0;
$i = $i++;
while($i>=0)
{
echo "<input type='radio' name='test[$i++]' value='test[$i++]'>test[$i++] ";
echo "<BR>";
$i++;

}
?>
```

UPDATE ***THIS WORKS!!!***

```
<?php

$i = 0;
while($i++ < 5) 
{
    echo "<input type='radio' name='test' value='test[$i]'>test[$i] ";
}
?>
```

Comment: so just dont change the name

Comment: if the name stays the same then only one will be selectable, you change the name with the loop so change `name='test[$i]'` to `name='test'`

Comment: Yes, know that...hence the increment loop... but not working.

Comment: know idea what you just said.

Comment: likewise...learn to spell.

Comment: yes, what I said to do half an hour ago worked, great. (homophone's are difficult for dyslexics, play nice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn basic PHP syntax. `"$i++"` is a string that contains a variable (`$i`), and two `+` characters. it's NOT going to increment your `$i` variable.

You're literally generating the following html:

```
<input type='radio' name='test[1++]' value='test[1++]'>test[1++]
<input type='radio' name='test[1++]' value='test[1++]'>test[1++]
<input type='radio' name='test[1++]' value='test[1++]'>test[1++]
```

As well, as written, your `while()` is going to be an infinite loop, since $i will ALWAYS be greater than 0.

Try this instead:

```
while($i++ < $limit) {
    echo "<input type='radio' name='test[$i]' value='test[$i]'>test[$i] ";
}
```

Comment: Thanks...I was trying to figure the increment bit out. I've updated my code, it loops a new ID but still can't select only one radio. :)

Comment: then look at your `view source` and see what the values are for your radio buttons. every "related" radio button must have the same name, but have different values.

Comment: Thanks for that - checked the source and the name values were incrementing too...removed the increment and hey presto! :)))

Answer (score 0):

you can use of bottom code.please preuse input tag(value).

```
`<?php for($i=1;$i<10;$i++) { `?>`
    <input name="RadioBox" type="radio" value="<?php print($i); ?>" />
    <?php } ?>
```